# How to secure the update operation in this scenario

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have an app that recommends gifts to the user, after they answer a couple of questions. In the case that the user likes or dislikes a gift, I need to send an update request to the db to update it's 'liked' field. Users are not required to sign in order to like/dislike questions. The app is built using Angular and used Express at the backend to do the CRUD operations.

My question was, is there any way this operation can be done in a secure way, so that the user can not open the dev tools and get the info which would enable them to send repeated requests or anything like that? Is there anything I can change in the Express code? Or would I need to change the security rules?

Answer (score 1):

Express should have a way to identify duplicate request. User id or some kind of token should be with request. But I see that sign-in of user not required in this case.

You can generate a temporary token every time some gifts are shown to user. This token should be generated and saved temporarily on express and you can send it with gifts data. So now when your frontend send request for like/dislike, this token will be in request.

So now express will do following steps

1. Checking if temp token is valid (it can match it with saved tokens)
2. If valid then it will update the database (like/dislike)
3. After successfully update it will remove that temp token.

So now, even if user send duplicate request it will be rejected by express as temp token will be not valid.

I hope it will solve your problem.